# How do I extract data from a spreadsheet for a given list of names?

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with >1000 names and almost everything someone might want to know about each name. If I have a shorter list of names (just names, and all of them on the larger list) and I want to select data for the names on the smaller list, is there a faster way than scrolling and manually selecting names from the larger list?

For example, If I have a list (names only) and want their contact info from the long list.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a VLOOKUP from each name in the shorter list to the contact info in the longer list.